# Visual Studio Code How to bring default font i got struck

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, console, editor

[image]

**By mistake i deleted default font of vs code now its showing some error.**
anyone can tell me default font of vscode so tht i can write moreover you can see my terminal font is also coming on Courier New.

**Need to change this HELP**

You can see the font

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gear icon to the left has an option to reset setting to default:

[image: reset_demo]